# ResultSetMappingBuilder query issue with ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following query:

```
    $max = 3;
    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM `prospective_shop` ps
            WHERE  ps.`approached_by_user` IS NOT NULL 
            AND    ps.`userid` 
            NOT IN (
                SELECT s.userid
                FROM  `instagram_shop` s
            )
            ORDER BY ps.`approacheddate` ASC
            LIMIT $max
            ";

    $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->_em);
    $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('App\MainBundle\Entity\ProspectiveShop', 'p'); 
    return $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)->getResult();
```

When I try to run this query the process never stops, took a very-very long time, I think there is an error in the:

```
ORDER BY ps.`approacheddate` ASC
```

when I remove this LINE everything works well. What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Add an index on approacheddate

Comment: @JoeTaras how do I add an index on a specific column?

Comment: ALTER TABLE `prospective_shop` ADD INDEX `approacheddateidx` (`approacheddate`). Tell me if it's ok, so I'll create a complete answer

Comment: @JoeTaras it's actually still taking a lot of time after adding the index

Comment: there's a lot of NULL value in that field?

Comment: Is it a typo in `$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('App\MainBundle\Entity\ProspectiveShop', 'p');`? It should be `$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('App\MainBundle\Entity\ProspectiveShop', 'ps');`

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov the query works out just fine, it's just flow